ImageView inside a RecyclerView Trimming from Right or Left
I have 3 imageviews inside a recyclerview. I am trying to drag right or left edge of the middle image view to trim it by altering the itemwidth of the recyclerview middle item. This results in trimming of width from left of the image view. How to trim it from the right ? I have tried by setting reverselayout is true and stackfromend to true but doesn't work.
How to implement drag to trim effect of the imageview inside the recyclerview from right or left of the imageview ?
I have tried by setting reverselayout is true and stackfromend to true but doesn't work.
